# Il non detto, i…?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idioms, plural

What is the plural of "non detto"?

[I non detto](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=Q0gYU7KOA4qb_waVwoCoBw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22i+non+detto%22)?

[I non detti](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=Q0gYU7KOA4qb_waVwoCoBw&gws_rd=cr#q=%22i+non+detti%22)?

The first sounds more correct to me. Does anyone know any source on this?

Comment: Yeah, "i non detti" <br> I'm italian! Bye!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree that *il non detto* might include literally everything untold, even if it's from many subjects or about many topics.
However, if one wants to underline that there are several hidden/inexplicit meanings, *i non detti* is usually used, according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=i+non+detto%2Ci+non+detti&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=22&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ci%20non%20detti%3B%2Cc0), in the books on rhetoric and communications, while *i non detto* has no mentions in the Italian corpus at all.
A [direct search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20non%20detti%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_it#q=%22i%20non%20detto%22&spell=1&tbm=bks) yields only one book, where it's actually used as *i "non detto"*, with quotation marks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm Italian and I would say that "i non detti" sounds more correct in my point of view, even if I would anyway prefer to use only "il non detto", including plural and singular.

Answer (score 4):

You really do not need the plural. "Il non detto" already includes, as set, all things that have been not told. It is like "Il pregresso" or "il già visto": it is the set of all the things already managed or seen

Comment: Consider that there might be different **sets** of unsaid, though, each characterized by different features. As in «… tutti “i non detto” di molti personaggi “illustri”…» or «…tutti i non-detto, le inquietudini, i sospiri, i momenti di silenzio, quelli di gioia e di sconforto…», etc.